# How to access RDS publicly?

Tags: amazon-web-services, postgresql, database, amazon-rds

I created a new RDS Postgres DB and I want to access it from a local computer.

I've checked the option to say yes to publicly accessible.

What are the other steps needed to access this?

I've tested with simple commands

```
psql --host=dev2.********.ca-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com --port=5432 --username=postgres
```

It times out

Here is my security setting for the db:

[image]

Here is my policy for that security group:

[image]

Comment: Modify the security group to permit traffic on port 5432 from your IP.

Comment: Uploaded screenshot showing the security group

Comment: Have a look at [this tutorial](https://www.percona.com/blog/2018/05/08/how-to-enable-amazon-rds-remote-access/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your screenshot of the security group shows you have **not** permitted public access. You've only allowed traffic from security group `sg-a5d469ca`. That rule doesn't cover your IP at all; you're not in a security group. Add a new rule, for port 5432, and pick "my IP" in the "source" dropdown.